# How to get values for session_isFirst using application insights query

Tags: azure, appinsights

Azure Application Insights continues export data json contains following fields,

```
"context": {
    "session": {
        "id": "5JMv4",
        "isFirst": false
    }
}
```

But I could not find this session IsFirst in app insights ( pageViews | getschema)
how azure is mapping this values in continues export, because I want to manually export data, and wants know from which field I need read data for isFirst fields.

Answer (score 0):

When we manually exporting data from Application Insights, we might have the option to include additional properties or manipulate the data before exporting it. In this case, `isFirst` appears to be a property that is derived or added during the export process, rather than being a native property of telemetry data.

- In Azure Application Insights, the `session_isFirst` property is typically not directly available as a top-level field in the `pageViews` table. Instead, it is derived or computed based on the session information available in the `context` field.

It means that the `session_isFirst` property is being derived from the `context.session.isFirst` field. To manually export this information, you would need to extract it from the `context` field.

**Query:**

```sql
pageViews
| project timestamp, user_Id, session_Id = tostring(customDimensions.SessionId), session_IsFirst = tostring(customDimensions.SessionIsFirst)
| summarize isFirstSession = any(session_IsFirst == "true"), count() by user_Id
| project user_Id, isFirstSession
```

Here I have Tracked a sample user sessions in Azure Application Insights and then exported the data manually.

[image]

- `customDimensions.SessionId` and `customDimensions.SessionIsFirst` are placeholders for the actual field names that the Application Insights schema might use.